# NameError: name 'ForeignKey' is not defined in my Django code

Tags: django, django-models

I am getiing an error Foreign Key not defined

```
task_name=ForeignKey(Task_List, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

> NameError: name 'ForeignKey' is not defined

models.py:

```
class Task_List(models.Model):
    task_name=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="NOT SPECIFIED")
    c1=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="OTHER")
    c2=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="OTHER")
    c3=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="OTHER")
    time_esc=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Task_manager(models.Manager):
    def create_Task(self, title):
        Task1 = self.create(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return Task1


class Task(models.Model):

    task_name=ForeignKey(Task_List, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30,default="Other", blank=Ture)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects=Task_manager()
    class Meta:
        ordering = [ '-created']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your question. You're more likely to get a response if you detail the steps you've taken to try to resolve the problem and where you're looked for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `models`, or conforming to your other field definitions, prefix it with `models.` like so:

```
task_name = models.ForeignKey(Task_List, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```